# Stuck in a question. Could you please give me a hint?.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

[image]

I have been stuck in this question for a while. I am not able to prove the first part. I have thought along the following possible directions:

1. I tried showing that $\mu^{*}(G^{c})=0$. However, I couldn't prove this.
2. I tried proving that if $B$ is in the given $\sigma$ field $\mathfrak{F}$ and $B$ contains $G \cap A $ then $\mu^{*}(B \setminus A)=0$.

However, I could't proceed much further while proving these. Could you please suggest me a good hint to solve the first part?

Also, for the second question, I aim to show that the set of $\mu^{*}$ measurable sets contains $\mathfrak{G}$. Now, restriction of $\mu^{*}$ to $\mu^{*}$ measurable sets is a measure. Will that be the correct approach?

Comment: 1. Please don't use pictures of text. [Read here why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). 2. please make subject lines relevant and informative as to the mathematics of your question, not about you. Your subject line isncompletely generic and uninformative, and so will fail to attract many who might be able to help.